# Creating a line grpah from array of data objects

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having this weird problem rendering a simple line graph from an array of parsed data objects with D3.

When I hardcode an array of data objects into my code, the graph will render fine. However, when I parse a JSON file, create a data object, and push it to an array, it won't render...

The two arrays (hardcoded vs. parsed) have the exact same data, yet only the hardcoded will render the graph.

Hardcoded data... ([creates graph](http://jsbin.com/zoyovevule/1/edit?js,output))

```
    var lineData =  [
                        {date: new Date("03/04/15"), rain: "2.2"},
                        {date: new Date("03/05/15"), rain: "2.3"},
                        {date: new Date("03/06/15"), rain: "0.0"},
                        {date: new Date("03/07/15"), rain: "2.0"},
                        {date: new Date("03/08/15"), rain: "5.0"},
                        {date: new Date("03/09/15"), rain: "2.3"},
                        {date: new Date("03/10/15"), rain: "15.0"},
                        {date: new Date("03/11/15"), rain: "0.0"},
                        {date: new Date("03/12/15"), rain: "7.0"},
                        {date: new Date("03/13/15"), rain: "0.0"},
                        {date: new Date("03/14/15"), rain: "1.0"},
                        {date: new Date("03/15/15"), rain: "0.0"},
                        {date: new Date("03/16/15"), rain: "2.3"},
                        {date: new Date("03/17/15"), rain: "8.0"},
                        {date: new Date("03/18/15"), rain: "1.4"},
                        {date: new Date("03/19/15"), rain: "0.0"},
                        {date: new Date("03/20/15"), rain: "1.0"}
                 ];            

var vis = d3.select("#visualisation"),
  WIDTH = 600,
  HEIGHT = 250,
  MARGINS = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 50
  },

xRange = d3.time.scale().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([d3.min(lineData, function (d) {
    return d.date;
  }),
  d3.max(lineData, function (d) {
    return d.date;
  })
]),

yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([d3.min(lineData, function (d) {
    return d.rain;
  }),
  d3.max(lineData, function (d) {
    return d.rain * 1.2;
  })
]),

xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(xRange)
  .tickSize(5),

yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(yRange)
  .tickSize(5)
  .orient("left");

vis.append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

vis.append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
  .call(yAxis);

var lineFunc = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function (d) {
    return xRange(d.date);
  })
  .y(function (d) {
    return yRange(d.rain);
  })
  .interpolate('linear');

vis.append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", lineFunc(lineData))
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .attr("stroke-width", .5)
  .attr("fill", "none");
```

Parsed JSON ([live example](http://jsbin.com/vobavobovi/1/edit?js,output))...

```
// global variables
var dailyRainTotal = 0,
    lineData = [],
    day = {};

// get the data
d3.json("https://api.myjson.com/bins/53grr", function(error, data) {

    // log the returned object on console unless error
    if (error) return console.error(error);
    console.log(data);

    var days = data.data.weather;

    // step through each day
    days.forEach(function(d) {

        // step through each hour
        d.hourly.forEach(function(h) {
            dailyRainTotal = dailyRainTotal + parseFloat(h.precipMM);
        });

        // add data to day
        day = {date: new Date(d.date), rain: dailyRainTotal.toFixed(2)};
        // push day to results array
        lineData.push(day);

        // reset the total
        dailyRainTotal = 0;
    });
});

var vis = d3.select("#visualisation"),
  WIDTH = 600,
  HEIGHT = 250,
  MARGINS = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 50
  },
xRange = d3.time.scale().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([d3.min(lineData, function (d) {
    return d.date;
  }),
  d3.max(lineData, function (d) {
    return d.date;
  })
]),

yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([d3.min(lineData, function (d) {
    return d.rain;
  }),
  d3.max(lineData, function (d) {
    return d.rain * 1.2;
  })
]),

xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(xRange)
  .tickSize(5),

yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(yRange)
  .tickSize(5)
  .orient("left");

vis.append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

vis.append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
  .call(yAxis);

var lineFunc = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function (d) {
    return xRange(d.date);
  })
  .y(function (d) {
    return yRange(d.rain);
  })
  .interpolate('linear');

vis.append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", lineFunc(lineData))
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .attr("stroke-width", .5)
  .attr("fill", "none");
```

When I check the console, the lineData array has the same format and values as the hardcoded data, yet the x/y axes, and line will not display. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

d3 `json` function is asynchronous. So your code to create the line is executed before the json data actually arrived. You need to move the line creation code into the `json` function:

```
d3.json("https://api.myjson.com/bins/53grr", function(error, data) {

    // log the returned object on console unless error
    if (error) return console.error(error);
    console.log(data);

    var days = data.data.weather;

    // step through each day
    days.forEach(function(d) {

        // step through each hour
        d.hourly.forEach(function(h) {
            dailyRainTotal = dailyRainTotal + parseFloat(h.precipMM);
        });

        // add data to day
        day = {date: new Date(d.date), rain: dailyRainTotal.toFixed(2)};
        // push day to results array
        lineData.push(day);

        // reset the total
        dailyRainTotal = 0;
    });

  var vis = d3.select("#visualisation"),
  WIDTH = 600,
  HEIGHT = 250,
  MARGINS = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 50
  },
xRange = d3.time.scale().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([d3.min(lineData, function (d) {
    return d.date;
  }),
  d3.max(lineData, function (d) {
    return d.date;
  })
]),

yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([d3.min(lineData, function (d) {
    return d.rain;
  }),
  d3.max(lineData, function (d) {
    return d.rain * 1.2;
  })
]),

xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(xRange)
  .tickSize(5),

yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(yRange)
  .tickSize(5)
  .orient("left");

vis.append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

vis.append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
  .call(yAxis);

var lineFunc = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function (d) {
    return xRange(d.date);
  })
  .y(function (d) {
    return yRange(d.rain);
  })
  .interpolate('linear');

vis.append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", lineFunc(lineData))
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .attr("stroke-width", .5)
  .attr("fill", "none");
});
```